# query Ordering not working in angularfire2

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

AngularFire2 ordering not working.

I have buttons which update 'order'. The right case of switch-case is getting triggered but the result remains same as the initial ordering.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-compact-research-report-list',
  template: `
    <loader *ngIf="!(allRRs$ | async)" [loading]=true [message]="'loading view...'"></loader>
    <ul class="list-unstyled clearfix">
      <li class="youtube-list-item" [@fadeIn] *ngFor="let rr of (allRRs$ | async)">
        <app-compact-research-report [media]="rr"></app-compact-research-report>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CompactResearchReportListComponent implements OnInit {
      public allRRs$: Observable<ResearchReport[]>;
      ngOnInit() {
        this.authService.reportDDBS$.subscribe((order) => {
          console.log('Reportorder = ' + order);
          switch (order) {
            case 'uploadDate':
              this.allRRs$ = this.dalService.this.afDb.list(`research_reports-published/`, ref => ref.orderByChild('uploadDate')).valueChanges();
              break;
            case 'filename':
              this.allRRs$ = this.dalService.this.afDb.list(`research_reports-published/`, ref => ref.orderByChild('filename').valueChanges();
              break;
            case 'uploaderName':
              this.allRRs$ = this.dalService.this.afDb.list(`research_reports-published/`, ref => ref.orderByChild('uploaderName').valueChanges();
              break;
            case 'revDownloads':
              this.allRRs$ = this.dalService.this.afDb.list(`research_reports-published/`, ref => ref.orderByChild('revDownloads').valueChanges();
              break;
            default:
              this.allRRs$ = this.dalService.this.afDb.list(`research_reports-published/`, ref => ref.orderByChild('uploadDate').valueChanges();
          }
        });
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with Firebase.
Changing `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` fixed it for me.